# Javascript: async function returning Promise object rather then string

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am simply trying to return a string after all the code in this function has finished exectued.

At the moment a Promise object is being added to the array rather then the strings that I expect.

What am I doing wrong ?

main.js

```
try {
  await filePaths.push(createCompaniesParquet(companiesDataset));
  await filePaths.push(createFacilitiesParquet(facilitiesDataset));
}catch(err){
  console.log(err)
}
console.log(filePaths)

var createCompaniesParquet = async(facilities)=>{
    var writerFacilitySchema = new parquet.ParquetSchema(facilitySchema);
    var writerFacility = await parquet.ParquetWriter.openFile(writerFacilitySchema, '/tmp/facilities.parquet');
    try{
        for (let index = 0; index < facilities.length; index++) {
            await writerFacility.appendRow({
                facility_commitment: false,
                facility_currency: 'GBP',
                facility_originator_lgd: 0.45,
                facility_originator_pd: 0.0, //TODO
                facility_security: TRUE, //TODO
                facility_id: '', //TODO
            });
        }
        await writerFacility.close();
    } catch(err){
        return err
    }
    return '/tmp/facilities.parquet'
}

var createFacilitiesParquet = async(facilities)=>{
        var writerFacilitySchema = new parquet.ParquetSchema(facilitySchema);
        var writerFacility = await parquet.ParquetWriter.openFile(writerFacilitySchema, '/tmp/facilities.parquet');
        try{
            for (let index = 0; index < facilities.length; index++) {
                await writerFacility.appendRow({
                    facility_commitment: false,
                    facility_currency: 'GBP',
                    facility_originator_lgd: 0.45,
                    facility_originator_pd: 0.0, //TODO
                    facility_security: TRUE, //TODO
                    facility_id: '', //TODO
                });
            }
            await writerFacility.close();
        } catch(err){
            return err
        }
        return '/tmp/facilities.parquet'
    }
```

With the above if I console log filePaths I get this:

```
[ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]
```

I was hoping to get this:

```
["/tmp/facilities.parquet","/tmp/facilities.parquet"]
```

Comment: try `filePaths.push(await createCompaniesParquet(companiesDataset))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Promise is in one of these states:

1. pending: initial state, neither fulfilled nor rejected.
2. fulfilled: meaning that the operation was completed successfully.
3. rejected: meaning that the operation failed.

So,if the operation was completed successfully,you can use `createFacilitiesParquet(params).then(val => {//do some thing})` ,the value of val is what you return in your function.